# load 'file.rb' versus require 'Module' in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

I am confused about the difference between `load 'file.rb'` and `require 'Module'`. At [Learn Ruby the Hard Way](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex40.html), the example of how to use a module is set up with two files (`mystuff.rb` and `apple.rb`):

mystuff.rb

```
module MyStuff
    def MyStuff.apple()
        puts "I AM APPLES!"
    end
end
```

apple.rb

```
require 'mystuff'

MyStuff.apple()
```

However, when I run `apple.rb`, either in the Sublime Text console, or with `ruby apple.rb`, I get a `Load Error`. I have also tried `require 'MyStuff'`, and `require 'mystuff.rb'`, but I still get the `Load Error`.

So, I switched the first line of `apple.rb` to `load 'mystuff.rb'`, which allows it to run. However, if I edit `'mystuff.rb'` to be a definition of `class MyStuff` as opposed to a `module MyStuff`, there is no difference.

For reference, the `Load Error` is:
`/Users/David/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in` require': cannot load such file -- mystuff (LoadError)`

I've peeked into `kernel_require.rb` and looked at the `require` definition, but since I'm a Ruby Nuby (indeed, a programming newbie), it was a little overwhelming. Since Learn Ruby the Hard Way hasn't been updated since 2012-10-05, there've probably been some syntax changes for modules. Yes?

Comment: Can you replace `require 'mystuff'` with `require_relative 'mystuff'`? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-require-relative-in-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this easily by changing

```
require 'mystuff'
```

to

```
require_relative './mystuff'
```

Answer (score 4):

`require` searches a pre-defined list of directories, as discussed in [What are the paths that "require" looks up by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474299/what-are-the-paths-that-require-looks-up-by-default). It's failing because it can't find the `mystuff.rb` in any of those directories.

`load`, on the other hand, will look for files in the current directory.

As for:

> However, if I edit 'mystuff.rb' to be a definition of class MyStuff as
>   opposed to a module MyStuff, there is no difference.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "no difference". If you mean that the `require` and `load` continue to fail and succeed, respectively, that makes sense, as the `require` failure is independent of the content of the file contents and the code you're testing behaves the same independent of whether Mystuff is a class or a vanilla module.