# Rspec error using ruby script: "cannot load such file -- ./components/tasks.rb" (ruby app not rails)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to build my Rspec testing test to test out a ruby app I am building. I know I should build first but test later. The code does work 100%  I am just having issues getting Rspec to even look at my code.

The full code on github:
https://github.com/EsdrasEtrenne/tictactoe

The only file that im running with rspec so far is ruby/spec/game_spec.rb

the game_spec.rb file looks like this:

```html
require_relative "../tictactoe"
Rspec.describe Tasks do
  before(:each)do
    @game = Tictactoe::Game.new
  end

  it "has a working method called play" do
    expect{@game.play}.to output("WELCOME! To the unbeatable Tic-tac-toe").to_stdout
  end
end
```

It requires tictactoe as a relative:

```html
require "./components/tasks.rb"
require "./components/board.rb"
require "./components/player.rb"
require "./components/player_types/computer.rb"
require "./components/player_types/human.rb"

module Tictactoe
  class Game
    attr_reader :board, :player, :opponent, :tasks

    def initialize
      @board = Board.new
      @tasks = Tasks.new
    end

    def play
      @tasks.greet_players
      @player, @opponent = @tasks.get_order
      current_player, current_opponent = @player, @opponent
      @tasks.print_board(@board)

      until @board.game_is_over || @board.tie
        @tasks.tell_turn(current_player)
        current_player.move(@board)
        @tasks.print_board(@board)
        if @board.game_is_over || @board.tie
          @tasks.game_over(@board)
          if @tasks.end_options
            game = Tictactoe::Game.new
            game.play
          end
        else
          current_player, current_opponent = current_opponent, current_player
        end
      end

    end

  end
end

game = Tictactoe::Game.new
game.play
```

Then I get this error when I run rspec game_spec.rb:

```html
An error occurred while loading ./game_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: return gem_original_require(path)

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- ./components/tasks.rb
# /Users/Esdras/Desktop/first_vagrant_box/coding_challenges/ruby/tictactoe.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
# ./game_spec.rb:1:in `require_relative'
# ./game_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00028 seconds (files took 0.08732 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

The game works 100% regularly. I just am looking to make the first test pass and from there the rest should be really straight forward.

Answer (score 7):

the `require` paths are resolved according to the *dir you're in when you're executing the code*. It's actually a bit more complicated than that, and there is this whole concept of "load path" which is configurable. See [What are the paths that "require" looks up by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474299/what-are-the-paths-that-require-looks-up-by-default)

From this line `An error occurred while loading ./game_spec.rb.` I'm figuring you've run `cd spec` then `rspec ./game_spec.rb` or something like that. I think your code would work if you were in the root of the project directory and ran `rspec spec/game_spec.rb`.

The benefit of `require_relative` over `require` is that the paths can be resolved no matter where you call the script from. I think if you used `require_relative` in tictactoe.rb it would work.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for tat. I knew it was something more simple.